# Dereferencing an offset from a null pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am reading a book on secure C coding which contains the following paragraphs.

> Dereferencing a null pointer usually results in a program crash, but
> dereferencing an offset from a null pointer allows an exploit to
> succeed without crashing the program.
>
> Assuming that temp_num , tmp2 , and num_of_records are under the
> control of a malicious user in the following example, the attacker can
> cause malloc() to fail by providing a large value for num_of_records:

```
signal_info * start = malloc(num_of_records * sizeof(signal_info));
signal_info * point = (signal_info *)start;
point = start + temp_num - 1;
memcpy(point->sig_desc, tmp2, strlen(tmp2));
/* ... */
```

> When malloc() fails, it returns a null pointer that is assigned to
> start . The value of temp_num is scaled by the size of signal_info when added to
> start . The resulting pointer value is stored in point . To exploit
> this vulnerability, the attacker can supply a value for temp_num that
> results in point referencing a writable address to which control is
> eventually transferred. The memory at that address is overwritten by
> the contents of the string referenced by tmp2 , resulting in an
> arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

My question relates to the line:

```
point = start + temp_num - 1;
```

`start` contains `NULL`. What does the author mean when he says `value of temp_num is scaled by the size of signal_info when added to start`, and why is the addition allowed with a NULL pointer ?

Comment: Are you already familiar with how C pointer arithmetic works in general, how offsets are always scaled internally by the size of the type?  It's just the same here, except that the starting address is 0.  The addition is "allowed" because the compiler never does any checks for the pointer being NULL, so there's nothing that would "disallow" it.

Comment: Of course this is all undefined behavior at the level of the C standard, so in that sense it's not "allowed".  But this discussion is about what typical implementations actually do when you write such code.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the systems today not only crash if a `NULL` pointer is dereferenced, but also on any pointer outside permitted address ranges. So the value of `temp_num` must be chosen in a way that the sum points into such a range. This must take the "scale" (multiplication by the size of `signal_info`) into account.

Some randomly presumed numbers:

- The size of `signal_info` is 0x1000.
- The address range of the attacker's target is 0x55000000 (inclusive) to 0x55008000 (exclusive).

Now let's reverse the math.

```c
point = start + temp_num - 1;
// now based on bytes:
[0x55000000 .. 0x55008000[ = NULL + (temp_num - 1) * 0x1000;
[0x55000 .. 0x55008[ = temp_num - 1;
[0x55001 .. 0x55009[ = temp_num;
```

So the needed value of `temp_num` must be in the range 0x55001 to 0x55008 inclusively.